# Do I need to compile ASIX Electronics AX88x7x/760 USB Ethernet driver to my kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, usb

I have box running

4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux

I also have this Moshi USB/Ethernet Combo [https://www.amazon.com/Moshi-USB-Gigabit-Ethernet-Adapter/dp/B00NMPB4H8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NMPB4H8), that has ASIX ax88760 chipset.

When I connect the USB device to the system the ethernet port does not appear to light up or be seen by the system as a functional NIC.  I did a bit of research (months ago) and found that most likely I need to install the drivers for this card.

Doing a quick google search `asix ax88760 ubuntu` led me to this page.
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man4/axe.4freebsd.html

That page states (screenshot)

[image: ASIX Man Page]

So my question is: Do I need to compile ASIX Electronics AX88x7x/760 USB Ethernet driver to my kernel? How would I definitely determine this?

Comment: That chipset is problematic...Even after you succeed in compiling the driver I am not sure you will be happy how it works.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Why would I be unhappy?

Comment: The chipset is not well supported and does not work well. I recommend researching well chipsets, including the need not to compile *before* buying them, not after.

Comment: And in general: Use `lsusb` or the lines in appear in `dmesg` after you plug in a USB device to find out it's vendor and device id (in the form 0123:4567).  This is also used to determine which kernel module gets loaded, check with `modinfo` and `lsmod`. On stock kernels, often all modules are compiled (unless experimental). You can check in the kernel configuration file (`.config`), which may or may not be in `/boot` depending on how Ubuntu does it.